# Django - how do you decide which model to put foreign key?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

Lets say I have two models that looks like this:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, unique_for_date="pub_date")


class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, unique_for_date="pub_date")
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

What is the difference between putting the `ForeignKey` (one-to-many) relationship on the `Track` model versus having a `many-to-many` on the `Album` model?

How does one decide such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Those would do completely different things.

Like you said, a ForeignKey is a one-to-many relationship. If you put it on Track, that means that many tracks belong to one album (or in other words, one album has many tracks). If you put it on Album, that means that many albums belong to one track, which is clearly not right.

The situation where there *is* a choice is when you're using a ManyToManyField. There, both sides are "many", so the choice of which side to put the field on is a purely semantic one.

**Edit** Again, these have different effects. A many-to-many would mean that both sides can have multiple items: an album can have many tracks *and* a track can belong to many albums.

Comment: Dang, I think thats what I was trying to ask.  It was a ManyToMany vs a oneToMany.  Let me edit the question.